# How to link quantity and a price

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a flexible pizza order form website. But I am having trouble linking the quantity with the price. For example if someone wants to order more than one pizza i would want the price multiplied by whatever their quantity is.

*UPDATE* I was told to put my entire code on here since I wasn't showing enough so here it is

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="./javascript/pizza.js"></script>

<script>

var address = window.prompt("Enter Your Address")

window.alert("The address you entered is: " + address)

filterSelection("all")

function filterSelection(c) {

var x, i;

x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");

if (c == "all") c = "";

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");

if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");

}

}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {

var i, arr1, arr2;

arr1 = element.className.split(" ");

arr2 = name.split(" ");

for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {

if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {

element.className += " " + arr2[i];

}

}

}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {

var i, arr1, arr2;

arr1 = element.className.split(" ");

arr2 = name.split(" ");

for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {

while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {

arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1); 

}

}

element.className = arr1.join(" ");

}

function getReceipt() {

var text1 = "<h3>You ordered: </h3>";

var runningTotal = 0;

var sizeTotal = 0;

var sizeArray = document.getElementsByClassName("size");

for (var i = 0; i < sizeArray.length; i++) {

if (sizeArray[i].checked) {

var selectedSize = sizeArray[i].value;

text1 = text1+selectedSize+"<br>";

}

}

if (selectedSize === "Personal Pizza") {

sizeTotal = 6;

}   

else if (selectedSize === "Medium Pizza") {

sizeTotal = 10;

}

else if (selectedSize === "Large Pizza") {

sizeTotal = 14;

}

else if (selectedSize === "Extra Large Pizza") {

sizeTotal = 16;

}

runningTotal = sizeTotal;

console.log("START of SIZE");

console.log(selectedSize+" = $" + sizeTotal + ".00");

console.log("size text1: " + text1);

console.log("subtotal: $" + runningTotal + ".00");

console.log("END of SIZE");

getMeat(runningTotal,text1);

};

function getMeat(runningTotal,text1) {

var meatTotal = 0;

var selectedMeat = [];

var meatArray = document.getElementsByClassName("meat");

console.log("START of MEAT");

for (var j = 0; j <meatArray.length; j++) {

if (meatArray[j].checked) {

selectedMeat.push(meatArray[j].value);

console.log("selected meat item: " + meatArray[j].value + "");

text1 = text1+meatArray[j].value+"<br>";

}

}

var meatCount = selectedMeat.length;

if (meatCount > 1) {

meatTotal = (meatCount -1);

}

else {

meatTotal = 0

}

runningTotal = (runningTotal + meatTotal);

console.log("total selected meat items: " + meatCount);

console.log(meatCount + " meat - 1 free meat = " + "$" + meatTotal + ".00");

console.log("meat text1: " + text1);

console.log("Purchase Total: " + "$" + runningTotal + ".00");

console.log("END of MEAT");

getVeg(runningTotal,text1);

};

function getVeg(runningTotal,text1) {

var vegTotal = 0;

var selectedVeg = [];

var vegArray = document.getElementsByClassName("veggies");

console.log("START of VEG");

for (var k = 0; k <vegArray.length; k++) {

if (vegArray[k].checked) {

selectedVeg.push(vegArray[k].value);

console.log("selected veg items: " + vegArray[k].value +"");

text1 = text1+vegArray[k].value+"<br>";

}

}

var vegCount = selectedVeg.length;

if (vegCount > 1) {

vegTotal = (vegCount -1);

}

else {

vegTotal = 0

}

runningTotal = (runningTotal + vegTotal);

console.log("total selected veg items: " + vegCount);

console.log(vegCount + " veg - 1 free veg = " + "$" + vegTotal + "0.00");

console.log("veg text1: " + text1);

console.log("Purchase Total: " + "$" + runningTotal + ".00");

console.log("END of VEG");

getCheese(runningTotal,text1);

}

function getCheese(runningTotal,text1) {

var cheeseTotal = 0;

var selectedCheese = [];

var cheeseArray = document.getElementsByClassName("cheeses");

for (var l = 0; l <cheeseArray.length; l++) {

if (cheeseArray[l].checked) {

var selectedCheese = cheeseArray[l].value;

console.log("START of CHEESE");

console.log("selected cheese items: " + cheeseArray[l].value + "");

text1 = text1+cheeseArray[l].value+"<br>";

}

}

var cheeseCount = selectedCheese.length;

if (selectedCheese === "Mozzarella Cheese") {

cheeseTotal = 0;

}   

else if (selectedCheese === "Extra Mozzarella") {

cheeseTotal = 3;

}

runningTotal = (runningTotal + cheeseTotal);

console.log("cheese value: " + cheeseTotal);

console.log("cheese text1: " + text1);

console.log("Purchase Total: " + "$" + runningTotal + ".00");

console.log("END of CHEESE");

getSauce(runningTotal,text1);

}

function getSauce(runningTotal,text1) {

var sauceArray = document.getElementsByClassName("sauces");

console.log("START of SAUCE")
        
for (var l = 0; l <sauceArray.length; l++) {

if (sauceArray[l].checked) {

var selectedSauce = sauceArray[l].value;

}

}
        
text1 = text1+selectedSauce+"<br>";

console.log("Selected Sauce: " + selectedSauce);

console.log("sauce text1: " + text1);

console.log("Purchase Total: " + "$" + runningTotal + ".00");

console.log("END of SAUCE");
        
getCrust(runningTotal,text1);

}

function getCrust(runningTotal,text1) {

var crustTotal = 0;

var selectedCrust = [];

var crustArray = document.getElementsByClassName("crusts");

for (var m = 0; m <crustArray.length; m++) {

if (crustArray[m].checked) {

var selectedCrust = crustArray[m].value;

console.log("START of CRUST");

console.log("selected crust items: " + crustArray[m].value + "");

text1 = text1+crustArray[m].value+"<br>";

}

}

var crustCount = selectedCrust.length;

if (selectedCrust === "Cheese Stuffed Crust") {

crustTotal = 3;

}   

else {

cheeseTotal = 0;

}

runningTotal = (runningTotal + crustTotal);

console.log("crust value: " + crustTotal);

console.log("crust text1: " + text1);

console.log("Purchase Total: " + "$" + runningTotal + ".00");

console.log("END of CRUST");

document.getElementById("disappearing-text").innerHTML = "";

document.getElementById("showText1").innerHTML = "<strong>She's a beauty, if I do say so myself.</strong>";

document.getElementById("showText2").innerHTML = text1;

function calculate(){

runningTotal = parseFloat(document.getElementById("runningTotal").innerHTML)

var totalprice = runningTotal * quantity.value

document.getElementById("totalprice").innerHTML = "<h3>Total: <strong>$"+ totalprice + ".00" + "</strong></h3>";

}

}

function clearAll() {

document.getElementById("disappearing-text").innerHTML = "<h4>Oops! Try building a pizza first.</h4>";

document.getElementById("frmMenu").reset();

document.getElementById("showText1").innerHTML = "";

document.getElementById("showText2").innerHTML = "";

document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML = "";

};


</script>
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>

<title>Pizza Palace</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="pizza.css">

</head>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top navbar-light" style="background-color:#e2e2e2">

<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">

<img src="pizza-icon.png" alt="pizza icon" style="width:50px;height:50px" href="#top"></a>

<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">

<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>

</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

<li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#top">Home</a></li>

<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#create">Create Your Pizza</a></li>

<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#work">See Your Work</a></li>

</ul>

</div>

</nav>

<header class="masthead text-center" id="top">

<div class="overlay"></div>

<div class="container">

<div class="row">

<div class="hungry-head col-xl-9 mx-auto my-5 py-2">

<h4 class="text-uppercase">Feeling Hungry?</h4>

<h1 class="mb-5">Create Your Dream Pizza</h1>
                
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning text-uppercase mb-2" style="width:200px" onclick=location.href="#create"><strong>Yes, I'm Hungry!

</strong>

</button>

</div>

</div>

</div>

</header>

<section class="create-pizza my-5 py-5" id="create">

<div class="container">

<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">

<div class="menu-content col-lg-10">

<div class="title text-center">

<h1 class="mb-10">Every pizza is a personal pizza,</h1>

<p>If you try hard and believe in yourself!</p>

</div>

</div>

</div>

<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">

<div class="col-md-3">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning text-uppercase mb-2" style="width:200px" onclick="getReceipt()"><a style="color:black;text-decoration:none" href="#work"><strong>Build My Pizza</strong></a></button>

</div>

<div class="col-md-3">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning text-uppercase mb-2" style="width:200px" onclick="clearAll()"><strong>Cancel &amp; Restart</strong>

</button>

</div>

</div>

<div class="myBtnContainer">

<ul>

<li class="active" onclick="filterSelection('all')">All</li>

<li class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('size')">Size</li>

<li class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('meat')">Meat</li>

<li class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('veggies')">Veggies</li>

<li class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('cheeses')">Cheeses</li>

<li class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('sauces')">Sauces</li>

<li class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('crusts')">Crusts</li>

</ul>

</div>

<form action="/action_page.php">

<div class="form-group">

<label for="email">Quantity:</label>
       
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" placeholder="Please enter quantity" name="quantity" value="1">
      
</div>

</form>

<div class="container filters-content">

<form id="frmMenu">

<div class="row">

<div class="filterDiv single-portfolio col-sm-4 all size">

<div class="item">

<label class="menu">

<input class="size" type="radio" name="Size" value="Personal Pizza"/>

<img src="size-personal.png" alt="personal size pizza" style="width:250px;height:250px">
                        
<p>Personal Pizza &mdash; $6.00</p>

</label>

</div>

</div>

<div class="filterDiv single-portfolio col-sm-4 all size">

<div class="item">

<label class="menu">

<input class="size" type="radio" name="Size" value="Medium Pizza" checked="checked"/>

<img src="size-medium.png" alt="medium size pizza" style="width:250px;height:250px">
                      
<p>Medium Pizza &mdash; $10.00</p>

</label>

</div>

</div>

<div class="filterDiv single-portfolio col-sm-4 all size">

<div class="item">

<label class="menu">

<input class="size" type="radio" name="Size" value="Large Pizza"/>

<img src="size-large.png" alt="large size pizza" style="width:250px;height:250px">
                     
<p>Large Pizza &mdash; $14.00</p>

</label>

</div>

</div>

<div class="filterDiv single-portfolio col-sm-4 all size">

<div class="item">

<label class="menu">

<input class="size" type="radio" name="Size" value="Extra Large Pizza"/>

<img src="size-xlarge.png" alt="extra large size pizza" style="width:250px;height:250px">
                      
<p>Extra Large Pizza &mdash; $16.00</p>

</label>

</div>

</div>

</div>

<div class="filterDiv meat container mt-5 mb-3">

<h5>Your first meat is free, additional meats are $1.00</h5>

</div>

<div class="row">

<div class="filterDiv single-portfolio col-sm-4 all meat">

<div class="item">

<label class="menu">

<input class="meat" type="checkbox" name="Meat" value="Anchovy"/>

<img src="anchovies.jpg" alt="anchovies" style="width:250px;height:250px">
                    
<p>Anchovy</p>

</label>

</div>

</div>

<div class="filterDiv single-portfolio col-sm-4 all meat">

<div class="item">

<label class="menu">

<input class="meat" type="checkbox" name="Meat" value="Canadian Bacon"/>

<img src="canadian-bacon.jpg" alt="canadian bacon" style="width:250px;height:250px">
                         
<p>Canadian Bacon</p>

</label>

</div>

</div>

<div class="filterDiv single-portfolio col-sm-4 all meat">

<div class="item">

<label class="menu">

<input class="meat" type="checkbox" name="Meat" value="Chicken"/>

<img src="chicken.jpg" alt="chicken" style="width:250px;height:250px">
                  
<p>Chicken</p>

</label>

</div>

</div>

<div class="filterDiv single-portfolio col-sm-4 all meat">

<div class="item">

<label class="menu">

<input class="meat" type="checkbox" name="Meat" value="Ground Beef"/>

<img src="ground-beef.jpg" alt="ground beef" style="width:250px;height:250px">
                      
<p>Ground Beef</p>

</label>

</div>

</div>

<div class="filterDiv single-portfolio col-sm-4 all meat">

<div class="item">

<label class="menu">

<input class="meat" type="checkbox" name="Meat" value="Pepperoni"/>

<img src="pepperoni.jpg" alt="pepperoni" style="width:250px;height:250px">
                            
<p>Pepperoni</p>

</label>

</div>

</div>

<div class="filterDiv single-portfolio col-sm-4 all meat">

<div class="item">

<label class="menu">

<input class="meat" type="checkbox" name="Meat" value="Sausage"/>

<img src="sausage.jpg" alt="sausage" style="width:250px;height:250px">
                            
<p>Sausage</p>

</label>

</div>

</div>

</div>

<div class="filterDiv veggies container mt-5 mb-3">

<h5>Your first veggie is free, additional veggies are $1.00</h5>

</div>

<div class="row">

<div class="filterDiv single-portfolio col-sm-4 all veggies">

<div class="item">

<label class="menu">

<input class="veggies" type="checkbox" name="Veggies" value="Green Peppers"/>

<img src="green-peppers.jpg" alt="green peppers" style="width:250px;height:250px">
                            
<p>Green Peppers</p>

</label>

</div>

</div>

<div class="filterDiv single-portfolio col-sm-4 all veggies">

<div class="item">

<label class="menu">

<input class="veggies" type="checkbox" name="Veggies" value="Jalapenos"/>

<img src="jalapenos.jpg" alt="jalapenos" style="width:250px;height:250px">
                            
<p>Jalapenos</p>

</label>

</div>

</div>

<div class="filterDiv single-portfolio col-sm-4 all veggies">

<div class="item">

<label class="menu">

<input class="veggies" type="checkbox" name="Veggies" value="Mushrooms"/>

<img src="mushrooms.jpg" alt="mushrooms" style="width:250px;height:250px">
                            
<p>Mushrooms</p>

</label>

</div>

</div>

<div class="filterDiv single-portfolio col-sm-4 all veggies">

<div class="item">

<label class="menu">

<input class="veggies" type="checkbox" name="Veggies" value="Olives"/>

<img src="olives.jpg" alt="olives" style="width:250px;height:250px">
                            
<p>Olives</p>

</label>

</div>

</div>

<div class="filterDiv single-portfolio col-sm-4 all veggies">

<div class="item">

<label class="menu">

<input class="veggies" type="checkbox" name="Veggies" value="Onions"/>

<img src="onions.jpg" alt="onions" style="width:250px;height:250px">
                            
<p>Onions</p>

</label>

</div>

</div>

<div class="filterDiv single-portfolio col-sm-4 all veggies">

<div class="item">

<label class="menu">

<input class="veggies" type="checkbox" name="Veggies" value="Pineapple"/>

<img src="pineapple.jpg" alt="pineapples" style="width:250px;height:250px">
                            
<p>Pineapple</p>

</label>

</div>

</div>

<div class="filterDiv single-portfolio col-sm-4 all veggies">

<div class="item">

<label class="menu">

<input class="veggies" type="checkbox" name="Veggies" value="Spinach"/>

<img src="spinach.jpg" alt="spinach" style="width:250px;height:250px">
                            
<p>Spinach</p>

</label>

</div>

</div>

<div class="filterDiv single-portfolio col-sm-4 all veggies">

<div class="item">

<label class="menu">

<input class="veggies" type="checkbox" name="Veggies" value="Tomatoes"/>

<img src="tomatoes.jpg" alt="tomatoes" style="width:250px;height:250px">
                            
<p>Tomatoes</p>

</label>

</div>

</div>

</div>

<div class="filterDiv veggies container mt-5 mb-3"></div>

<div class="row">

<div class="filterDiv single-portfolio col-sm-4 all cheeses">

<div class="item">

<label class="menu">

<input class="cheeses" type="radio" name="Cheeses" value="Mozzarella Cheese" checked="checked"/>

<img src="mozzarella-cheese.jpg" alt="mozzarella cheese" style="width:250px;height:250px">
                            
<p>Mozzarella Cheese</p>

</label>

</div>

</div>

<div class="filterDiv single-portfolio col-sm-4 all cheeses">

<div class="item">

<label class="menu">

<input class="cheeses" type="radio" name="Cheeses" value="Extra Mozzarella"/>

<img src="extra-mozzarella.jpg" alt="extra mozzarella cheese" style="width:250px;height:250px">
                            
<p>Extra Mozzarella &mdash; $3.00</p>

</label>

</div>

</div>
<div class="filterDiv single-portfolio col-sm-4 all cheeses">

<div class="item">

<label class="menu">

<input class="cheeses" type="radio" name="Cheeses" value="No Cheese"/>

<img src="no-cheese.jpg" alt="no cheese" style="width:250px;height:250px">
                            
<p>No Cheese</p>

</label>

</div>

</div>

</div>

<div class="filterDiv veggies container mt-5 mb-3"></div>

<div class="row">

<div class="filterDiv single-portfolio col-sm-4 all sauces">

<div class="item">

<label class="menu">

<input class="sauces" type="radio" name="Sauces" value="Marinara Sauce" checked="checked"/>

<img src="marinara-sauce.jpg" alt="marinara sauce" style="width:250px;height:250px">
                            
<p>Marinara Sauce</p>

</label>

</div>

</div>

<div class="filterDiv single-portfolio col-sm-4 all sauces">

<div class="item">

<label class="menu">

<input class="sauces" type="radio" name="Sauces" value="Barbecue Sauce"/>

<img src= "bbq-sauce.jpg" alt="barbecue sauce" style="width:250px;height:250px">
                            
<p>Barbecue Sauce</p>

</label>

</div>

</div>

<div class="filterDiv single-portfolio col-sm-4 all sauces">

<div class="item">

<label class="menu">

<input class="sauces" type="radio" name="Sauces" value="White Sauce"/>

<img src="white-sauce.jpg" alt="white sauce" style="width:250px;height:250px">
                            
<p>White Sauce</p>

</label>

</div>

</div>

<div class="filterDiv single-portfolio col-sm-4 all sauces">

<div class="item">

<label class="menu">

<input class="sauces" type="radio" name="Sauces" value="No Sauce"/>

<img src="no-sauce.jpg" alt="no sauce" style="width:250px;height:250px">
                            
<p>No Sauce</p>

</label>

</div>

</div>

</div>

<div class="filterDiv veggies container mt-5 mb-3"></div>

<div class="row">

<div class="filterDiv single-portfolio col-sm-4 all crusts">

<div class="item">

<label class="menu">

<input class="crusts" type="radio" name="Crusts" value="House Special Crust" checked="checked"/>

<img src="house-special-crust.png" alt="house special crust" style="width:250px;height:250px">
                                
<p>House Special Crust</p>

</label>

</div>

</div>

<div class="filterDiv single-portfolio col-sm-4 all crusts">

<div class="item">

<label class="menu">

<input class="crusts" type="radio" name="Crusts" value="Cheese Stuffed Crust"/>

<img src="cheese-stuffed-crust.jpg" alt="cheese stuffed crust" style="width:250px;height:250px">
                                
<p>Cheese Stuffed Crust &mdash; $3.00</p>

</label>

</div>

</div>

<div class="filterDiv single-portfolio col-sm-4 all crusts">

<div class="item">

<label class="menu">

<input class="crusts" type="radio" name="Crusts" value="Garlic Butter Crust"/>

<img src="garlic-crust.jpg" alt="garlic crust" style="width:250px;height:250px">
                            
<p>Garlic Butter Crust</p>

</label>

</div>

</div>

<div class="filterDiv single-portfolio col-sm-4 all crusts">

<div class="item">

<label class="menu">

<input class="crusts" type="radio" name="Crusts" value="Plain Crust"/>

<img src="plain-crust.jpg" alt="plain crust" style="width:250px;height:250px">
                            
<p>Plain Crust</p>

</label>

</div>

</div>

<div class="filterDiv single-portfolio col-sm-4 all crusts">

<div class="item">

<label class="menu">

<input class="crusts" type="radio" name="Crusts" value="Spicy Crust"/>

<img src="spicy-crust.jpg" alt="spicy crust" style="width:250px;height:250px">
                            
<p>Spicy Crust</p>

</label>

</div>

</div>

</div>

</form>

</div>

<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">

<div class="col-md-3">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning text-uppercase mb-2" style="width:200px" onclick="getReceipt()"><a style="color:black;text-decoration:none" href="#work"><strong>Build My Pizza</strong></a></button>

</div>

<div class="col-md-3">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning text-uppercase mb-2" style="width:200px" onclick="clearAll()"><strong>Cancel &amp; Restart</strong></button>

</div>

</div>

</div>

</section>

<section class="my-5 py-5" id="work">

<div class="container">

<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center my-5">

<div class="col-lg-10 text-center">

<h1 class="mb-10">Check Out Your Work</h1>

</div>

</div>

<center>*only delivers to Saskatoon, Saskatchewan*</center>

<div class="price-top row d-flex py-3 justify-content-center mt-5" id="showText1">

<div class="col text-center">

<p></p>

</div>

</div>

<div class="price-bottom py-4 row d-flex justify-content-center">

<div class="col-md-4 text-center" id="showText2"></div>

<div class="col-md-4 text-center" id="totalPrice"></div>

</div>

<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center mt-3" id="disappearing-text">

<h4>Oops! Try building a pizza first</h4>

</div>

</div>

</section>

<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="footer text-center py-4 row">

<div class="col-3">

<a href="#top">Back to Top</a>

</div>

<div class="col-9">

<a>© 2019</a>
  
</div>

</div>

</div>
```

When i do this i get NaN but what I want is for the price to be multiplied

Comment: What is `runningTotal`? Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Are `runningTotal` or `quantity` strings? If you set `runningTotal = input.value`, it will be a string, so you need to use `runningTotal = parseFloat(input.value)`

Comment: Oh sorry runningTotal is all the topping prices added together

Comment: I guess quantity is undefined or InputElement and when you trying multiplying it with a number it returns NaN.

Comment: please add code snippet from where `runningTotal` originated.

Comment: I changed my code a bit but now I'm get nothing where the price should be is blank

Comment: what about `quantity` I don't see that assigned anywhere.

Comment: Its in the html section

Comment: Please fix the syntax errors in your snippet. Basically your HTML does not really relate to the javascript you have provided

Comment: ids `showText1` and `showText1` are not present in your html you are using, moreover, `text1` var is not present too !

Comment: We don't need your entire code, we need just enough code to replicate the issue. Please see: [mcve] . Note, both minimal and reproducible.

Comment: For us to help you we need enough code to reproduce the issue, but only code that is directly related to the issue. By reducing the code to the minimal amount to reproduce the issue, you may find the problem itself. Make sure to resolver any errors that appear when you hit "Run Code Snippet" there are several at the moment that are not the problem as described.

Answer (score 0):

First of All you should have one Label to show product Price ( Get Data from Your Model Layer in Server and Place it at Label)
and a Number Input to get Product quantity From user + Total Price Label

after that, you have set an onchange listener on your number input
in your event Handler you can calculate total price by multiple product quantity on product price

Note: NaN in Javascript is Result of Operating on a number with None number value
      innerHTML will not return a number to you, so you have cast it to number, By using
      Number(document.getElementById("test").innerHTML)

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body style="margin: 10px">

<div id="product12">

<label for="product12-price">item price :</label>
<span id="product12-price" product-id="12">5</span>
<span id="product12-price-unit">$</span>


    <div id="product12-quantity-container" style="margin-top: 10px;">
        <input type="number" id="product12-quantity" min="0" max="10">
    </div>

</div>

<div id="total-price-container" style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <span id="total-price-caption">total price :</span>
    <span id="total-price">0</span>
    <span id="total-price-unit">$</span>
</div>

<script>
    var product12_quantity = document.getElementById("product12-quantity");
    var total_price = document.getElementById("total-price");
    product12_quantity.addEventListener("change", function () {
        total_price.innerHTML = Number(document.getElementById("product12-price").innerHTML) * Number(product12_quantity.value);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to say

Comment: do not worry, i am going to make a live example for you

Answer (score 0):

Few of the links seems missing in your code, I have tried filling those in. TRy using the below code and see if you are able to calculate the cost. 
If still face problem post your complete code here.

```js
var runningTotal = 0;



console.log("Purchase Total: " + "$" + runningTotal + ".00");
console.log("END of CRUST");


function calculate()  {
  var sizeTotal = 0;
  runningTotal = parseFloat(document.getElementById("perPizzaCost").innerHTML)
  totalprice = runningTotal * quantity.value;

  document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML = "<h3>Total: <strong>$" + totalprice + ".00" + "</strong></h3>";
}
```

```html
<label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>

<input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" placeholder="Please enter quantity" name="quantity" value="1" onChange="calculate()">
<div> Per Pizza Cost : <span id="perPizzaCost">200</span>$ </div>

<div id="totalPrice"></div>
```